# Display name for DEB package in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, package-management, packaging, deb

Suppose I have a package mypack_1.1.0_i386.deb.
When I open it via Ubuntu Software Center it displays "mypack" as a display name.
Obviously it gets the name from the "Package:" attribute of the 'control' file from the package.
But there are packages with short package name in "Package:" attribute and more verbose display name in Ubuntu Software Center.

Is it possible to specify somewhere verbose display name for my package? Or for those packages USC get the display name from some internet database somehow?

I tried to use multiline "Description:" field in config file but this doesn't help.

Comment: Good question. I've downloaded a full-featured package source with verbose information in the USC, but this information wasn't present in there. I guess this is published by Ubuntu on their remote package database like the ratings by users.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested about `apt-cache` command with `show` option. For example, if you want to know the name for `gimp` package, run the following command in terminal:

```
apt-cache show gimp | grep "Filename:"
```

In general, for a package called `package`, you can use:

```
apt-cache show package | grep "Filename:" | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }
```